# Can poor performance be considered as a software bug?

Tags: performance, software-design

Recently, I worked on a ticket where the code produced the expected output for controlled input. The code passed unit testing, integration testing, and regression testing. However, when the input was large, the code was very, very slow to return an output, although when it eventually returned the output, the results were correct. Needless to say, we didn't do all the exhaustive testing we could have (e.g. acceptance testing) as there are too many variables to explore and control for (e.g. environments mimicking different deployment sites).

A co-worker of mine said that because the code was so slow, it was a "bug." I completely disagreed with the co-worker. To me, I (naively) defined a (software) bug as any programming code that produces incorrect output. The co-worker added to my definition, a software bug as any programming code that produces incorrect output, behavior, and/or side-effects; side-effects including long processing time for huge inputs.

Nevertheless, we argued as I insisted it was a performance issue and not a bug, and the co-worker vice-versa. This point of contention was important because the problem (a bug and/or performance issue) was observed in a code branch that was bug-fix only (no new features, only bug-fixes). Whether it was a bug or not would determine where the fix would go (I wasn't trying to get out of work).

So, I posed the question, is Quick Sort a bug? It's worst-case running time complexity is O(n^2). For a huge input, Quick Sort would be considered a bug because of performance issue for my co-worker, but not under my definition. But if performance determined or influence the problem's dimension of being or bug or not, for a small input, Quick Sort would not be a bug. So, it seems to me, that performance should be almost precipitated out as a factor for determining whether a problem is a bug or not.

I'd like some community feedback on how to define software bugs beyond textbooks and Wikipedia, and from a practitioner's experience. I think my definition is too narrow, but I believe my co-worker's definition is too broad. But I still stand by my intuition and "feeling" that performance problems are not (should not be considered) software bugs, at least not on the surface (there could be a real actual bug causing the performance issue).

May I amend this post and say, from a programmer's perspective, and minimizing customers/users as much as possible.

Comment: bug = unexpected behavior. if you buy a ferrarri and it can't go accelerate past 1nanometer/millenium, then that'd be a bug...

Comment: What might be an interesting read for you is this article on codinghorror.com: http://blog.codinghorror.com/thats-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-request/ *One of my favorite things about UserVoice -- which we use for Stack Overflow -- is the way it intentionally blurs the line between bugs and feature requests. Users never understand the difference anyway, and what's worse, developers tend to use that division as a wedge against users.*

Comment: Marc has a point about unexpected behaviour. From the users perspective, the thing that was built didn't work.  If you use Quick Sort in an implementation that is supposed to solve some problem, and it doesn't solve it fast enough, that can be considered a bug. Flipping the question around...is sneaking  [BogoSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) into your app **not** a bug?

Comment: If it's a quicksort when it wasn't intended to be (broken introsort, perhaps?), that's a bug.

Comment: A maintenance-only branch is there to solve problems, and performance unusably below specifications _is_ a problem. Don’t get hung up on what to call it.

Answer (score 4):

The term bug originated with an actual insect that was found impeding the movement of mechanical relays in an early computer (I don't know if this story is apocryphal or not).  The current use of the word is vague and, in your case, harmful to productivity.  The term 'defect' is more useful.  As well, many people use the term 'bug' if a program throws an unexpected exception or crashes.  This goes beyond your definition of an incorrect output.

Since system performance is or should be part of the system requirements, you have a design defect only if you decide that the performance does not meet your requirements.  In your question, if 'quick sort' does not meet requirements, then incorporating it into your solution is a design defect.  If the requirements were not sufficiently complete to specify performance, then it was a defect in the requirements.  I have often used the term 'bug' when referring to such a defect (as in, "there is a bug in the spec").

So fix the spec, and let the project manager decide which branch includes the implemented rework.  In my experience, this is based on perceived or actual user acceptability.

Answer (score 2):

Please start by stating your SLA (service level agreement). If SLA includes non-functional requirements such as performance, please listed it here as well, be it constant limit, or a function of input size. No SLA - no bug.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic debates between developers can last an eternity with no resolution in sight. Among users, anything exceptional that is very different from what was expected (including exceptionally slow performance) can count as a "bug".

I personally prefer that *"correctness-first"* conventional wisdom, as I have never been bitten too badly by something that was functioning correctly but just needed an implementation-level optimization. I have been bitten by getting too excited optimizing something that I didn't thoroughly test, and discovering new use cases where I screwed myself and put myself in a corner with the former optimizations.

*"A program that produces incorrect results twice as fast is infinitely slower." — John Osterhout*

... but of course, this is just a point of view (and what about approximations?). Everyone has a point of view, and they're all potentially different.

We can try to take the subjectivity out of the scenario and create formal specifications of what is and isn't to be expected out of various parts of the software, but performance is often *discovered* in hindsight with a profiler in hand and unanticipated use cases, not foreseen perfectly in advance.

Some things that might be interesting to note is that in certain kinds of mission-critical software, a significant spike in performance could get someone killed if they were relying on a prompt response. In such a case, it's much easier to define such unexpected delays as a glitch, but it doesn't sound like you're working on such a mission-critical software.

It's also worth noting the way people psychologically look at performance. For example, if you have a progress bar that's steadily moving even though an operation takes a long time, it tends to make people accept the delay as being "normal" much more than if your software simply becomes unresponsive for a long time with no indicator of what's happening. Things actually tend to "feel" faster as well as "functional" with a progress indicator.

The real problem I see here is that you two are arguing over whether something is defective or not when it shouldn't need to be this stressful. This is all in the realm of software *improvement*, and we can be doing much more exciting things than arguing like working together to optimize those things which are, indeed, measured performance bottlenecks. I've worked with people who place all their focus on performance hunches without even using a profiler and without placing nearly as much attention on correctness, and they can make things unpleasant for everyone around them, so you have my condolences if you're working with one of those types.

When we're in a bug-fix only branch, I'd just communicate with the rest of the team as a whole and try to determine if an optimization should go in or not, and perhaps also make the point that if it's not something that is currently dissatisfying users tremendously, that saving the optimization as a future improvement may be quite smart from a business point of view (it's not necessarily smart to cram every improvement you can into one update).